# python - regex replace list of words in a string with nothing

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

Someone help me to get this right. Some tricky patterns in the address field. Some users entering both street names and suburb name in the street name field. Need to clean them. But the clean up gets tricky because of the two scenarios -

1. Street name and suburb name are same sometimes
2. Multiple word suburb name with space in between them.

Examples:-

```
df1

Street_Name
Point Chevalier Road Point Che
Point Chevalier Road Point Ch
Point Chevalier Road Point Cheval
Point Chevalier Road Point Chevalier
Kings Road Point Chevalier
Point Chevalier
```

The logic here is to remove only the second matching word if there is more than one. If there is only one matching but there is some other words in front, then that should be "road or street name + suburb name", so remove suburb name from that. If it has just the matching word in the field, just leave it as it is.

output should be,

```
Street_Name
Point Chevalier Road
Point Chevalier Road
Point Chevalier Road
Point Chevalier Road
Kings Road
Point Chevalier
```

We can have all the possibilities of the suburb names in a stop word list. something like this,

```
stopwords = ['point c','point ch','point che','point chev','point cheva','point cheval','point chevali','point chevalie','point chevalier']
```

**EDIT:**

This is what I tried, but it doesn't help :(

```
def remove_if_suburb_name(s):
    stopwords = ('point c','point ch','point che','point chev','point cheva','point cheval',
                'point chevali','point chevalie')
    for word in stopwords:
        m = re.sub(r'\b'+ word + r'\b','', s.lower(), count = 2)
        return m

test['new_street_name'] = test['Street_Name'].apply(lambda x: remove_if_suburb_name(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)
```

Comment: What have you tried for solving?

Comment: Updated the question with what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
(.*)(point\s+c\w+)(.*)point\s+c\w+(.*)|(.+)\bpoint\s+c\w+(.*)
```

And replace by:

```
\1\2\3\4\5\6
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pevE4g/1/)

Sample Source: ( [Run Here](http://ideone.com/Q0OSyU) )

```
import re
regex = r"(.*)(point\s+c\w+)(.*)point\s+c\w+(.*)|(.+)\bpoint\s+c\w+(.*)"
test_str = ("Street_Name\n"
    "Point Chevalier Road Point Cheva\n"
    "Point chevalier Road Point Chev\n"
    "Point Chevalier Road Point Cheval\n"
    "Point Chevalier Road Point Chevali\n"
    "Kings Road Point Chevalier\n"
    "Point Chevalier")

subst = "\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
if result:
    print (result)
```

Update:

You should construct a dictionary , and apply the regex mentioned above and get stop point from your dictionary and convert... I think that will be more feasible and understandable to all. So what you need to do is to put variable in place of point\s+c\w+ in the above regex and get data from your stop word dictionary

Comment: Thanks, but its not only point chevalier, I have different suburb names to be used. So the stop word will look like ('western springs','western spring','western sprin','western spri','western spr','western sp','western s',
            ,'point chevalie','point chevali','point cheval','point cheva','point chev', 'point che','point ch','point c')

Comment: You should construct a dictionary , and apply the regex mentioned above and put stop point from your dictionary and convert... I think that will be more feasible and understandable to all. So what  you need to do is to put variable in place of point\s+c\w+ in the above regex and put data from your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I'd search for "Point c" not in the beginning of a logical line.

```
import re


string = '''
Street_Name
Point Chevalier Road Point Che
Point Chevalier Road Point Ch
Point Chevalier Road Point Cheval
Point Chevalier Road Point Chevalier
Kings Road Point Chevalier
Point Chevalier
'''


def remove_if_suburb_name(data, suburb_startswith):
    return re.sub(r'(?<!^) {}.*'.format(suburb_startswith), '', data, flags=re.MULTILINE)


print(remove_if_suburb_name(data=string, suburb_startswith="Point C"))

# Street_Name
# Point Chevalier Road
# Point Chevalier Road
# Point Chevalier Road
# Point Chevalier Road
# Kings Road
# Point Chevalier
```

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jYaTnG/1)

Comment: what about  those - "Point Chevalier Road Point Che ma po che"  and " Point Chevalier Road Point Cheval"

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman well, you're right - to work with spaces in the beginning of the logical lines, multiline flag is needed. Editing answer and [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jYaTnG/3)

Comment: You removed "ma po che" in the tail as well. which is not sub urb name

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman is this one better? [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jYaTnG/4) (of course, it works only if there are no more words in suburb name which beginnings aren't being matched in the regex)